# Inverse square law in one dimension

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, celestial-mechanics

A point of mass $m$ is at rest at position $b$  and subjected to a force $f(x) = -k x^2$.  We are to show that the time required for the particle to reach the origin is

$$ \pi \left( \frac{m b^3}{8 k}\right)^{1/2} $$

I set up the problem from Newton's second law $ m \frac{d^2 x}{dt^2} = -k x^2$.  This differential equation can be solved by substituting $y = \frac{dx}{dt}$ to get $y \frac{dy}{dx} = -k x^2$, a separable ODE.  Solving this equation with the boundary conditions I believe I get $t = \left( \frac{m b^3}{8 k}\right)^{1/2}$ for $x = 0$.  This is off by a factor of $\pi$.  Any pointer on where I am going wrong would be appreciated.

Ex 2.3 from Fitzpatrick's Celestial Mechanics.  This is not for a class, but self study.

Comment: Nothing seems wrong about your answer, maybe there is an error on the answer given.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only factor of $\pi$ in the problem comes from the final integral you have to do, which in dimensionless form is
$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{\frac{u}{1-u}} du = \frac{\pi}{2}$$
This integral is pretty hard, so if you did it quickly (which I think you did, since you didn't mention any painful integrals here), then you made a mistake here.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems the correct solution to the differential equation resulting from substitution is:

$$ \frac{dx}{dt} = \left( \frac{2k}{m} \frac{b-x}{bx} \right)^{1/2} $$

If one does not solve the IVP correctly, then there is no $b$ in the equation and there is no tricky integral remaining.